# Is there a way to put all modals in one file and trigger them throughout the website?

Tags: php, jquery, html, wordpress, bootstrap-modal

I am developing a WordPress theme that has three different modals, these modals will be triggered throughout the website based on user interaction. These modals all have to be able to be triggered from *every* page on the site, at *any* time **if** the conditions are met.

Everything works great if I implement the same modals *over* and *over* again on every page-template, but that's far from a viable solution.

I've read up on the data-targets and the other possibilities that the Bootstrap Documentation offers, but I'm not feeling it. There has to be a simple way of achieving this. I just want to put all my modals into one file called `my-modals.php` and simply trigger *any* of them *whenever* I need to throughout the site.

I've been thinking about creating a function for it, or maybe use `<?php include(); ?>` or `<?php get_template_part(); ?>` for the file, but I just can't *"shake that feeling"* that some of the geniuses on this site has a correct answer to this.

I am not asking about how to create simple trigger functions or anything like that. Everything works fine whenever I put the **entire** modal markup on the page I trigger it from.

My question is how to trigger the modals I need, whenever I need them from **ONE** source?

Comment: All you need to do is place the required HTML and JS on every single page. [`wp_footer`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_footer) is probably the best hook for it. If you want to load the markup dynamically you'll probably want to use [front-end ajax](https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins#Ajax_on_the_Viewer-Facing_Side).

Comment: I *think* understand what you are saying @AndreiGheorghiu. But is there not another way of doing this? Include the file somehow like it was a library, and trigger it whenever I need to throughout the site? Putting my triggers throughout the site is not a problem. That's just two line of Javascript, the problem is that they basically have nothing to trigger if they don't have access to the source somehow.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do that by creating the modals with a different ids which will be called on click of the respective button or links rather than popuped automatically. I suggest you to write all the modals in single file but put into the condition if possible, just like below :

```
 <?php 

 if(is_home())
 {
 ?>
  <!-- Your Modal for Home Page only -->
 <?php 

 }
 if(is_category())
 {
 ?>
  <!-- Your Modal for Category Pages -->
 <?php

 }
```

Comment: I have every condition in place for *when* they'll be triggered. The problem is, how to trigger all the modals from only one file, without *bloating* the site with duplicate markups.

Comment: You need to write the respective Javascript code on click of the button or link. Like : $('.x-button').on('click',function(){ $('#xModal').modal() });  
$('.y-button').on('click',function(){ $('#yModal').modal() });